# Is it safe to use repos of old release in a newer one?

Tags: package-management, repository, software-sources

I found these instructions in [this documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/cocos2d-x/en/installation/Linux.html) for Ubuntu 17.x and 18.x:

> Add a repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> ```
> deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main
> ```
>
> Install dependencies.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install g++ libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev python-pip cmake libx11-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgl2ps-dev libxi-dev libzip-dev libpng-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfontconfig1-dev libsqlite3-dev libglew-dev libssl-dev libgtk-3-dev libglfw3 libglfw3-dev xorg-dev
> ```
>
> Is it safe?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is instructing to add that repo because I just did a simulated run installing those dependencies and it didn't complain about finding any of them. I'm on Ubuntu desktop 17.10 amd64.

Comment: @Paul Tanzini yeah, but if there would be necessity - it's not safe, right ?

Comment: The truth is "it depends" and there is no general yes/no answer to this question.

Comment: I wouldn't do it personally. The best info I have found is for Debian, which Ubuntu is very close to Debian. This link says it should be ok: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60555/debian-is-it-possible-safe-to-install-packages-from-an-older-version-of-the-rep Again, I don't know if it is safe. So please have a back-up if you do try.